# What happened to the virus that scanned for insecurities?

Tags: plot-explanation, ralph-breaks-the-internet

In *Ralph Breaks the Internet* there was a black color snake like virus with one eye. What happened to it? Was it a plothole?

Comment: A plothole is an inconsistency. This is simply something that was overlooked (or perhaps cut from the film).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took the form of Ralph. Once Ralph's insecurities are addressed, Arthur (the name of the virus) disappears.